# Unable to boot the simulator

Tags: swift

Здравствуйте, хотела запустить приложение на симуляторе, а тут ошибка такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

А при запуске компьютера появляется такая ошибка: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это все симуляторы или один конкретный?

Comment: Все симуляторы...

Comment: Включается только на реальном устройстве

Comment: ну чисто для поддержания разговора - место на диске не могло кончиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решила проблему, нужно было просто до Сиерра систему обновить)
Спасибо за ответы

Comment: предположу, что имеется ввиду Сиерра а не Сири

Answer (score 0):

Доброе время суток, 
скорей всего у вашему компу не хватает оперативной памяти 
или же вам нужно это посмотреть

[image: как добавить симулятор][image: добавление симулятора]

Comment: А зачем загружать симулятор?

Comment: не загрузить  а выбрать другой либо подключить какое то устройство на iOS